# Firebase limitToLast is not defined?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to limit number of item to return when watch the 'value'
Why I get undefined error run orderByChild on my Firebase ref?

```
   $scope.watchRef = new Firebase(ActiveFirebase.getBaseURL() + "/sessions);

   $scope.watchRef.limitToLast(2).on('value', function(){})
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you double-check the code fragment please. It currently contains a syntax error (that I doubt you have in your real code) *and* it doesn't contain a call to `orderByChild` which you mention in your description (but not in the title of the question).

Answer (score 2):

Which version of the Firebase web client library are you using? Per the [Firebase Web Client Changelog](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html), the `FirebaseRef.limitToLast()` method was added in v2.0.0 / Nov. 4, 2014.